# How to get clean bed linens at hotels?

Tags: hotels, hygiene

At the hotel I'm staying at right now I've noticed that the bed linens aren't changed when the room and bed are made. Towels are changed only if put on the floor but that isn't unusual.

How can I make the cleaners know that I want fresh bed linens?

- Should I just pull them off the bed and put them on the bed?
- Put them on the floor?
- In the bathroom?
- Ask the reception?
- Leave a note in the room?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Many hotels have a card somewhere in the room that explains that in order to save the environment they will not change the bed linens every day if you are staying more than one day. This card should also say that they will change the bed linens if you put that very card on the bed so that it is clearly visible to housekeeping staff.

Here is an example card.

[image: Change hotel bed sheets card]

If you can't find such a card in the room, you can always ask the front desk what to do.

Comment: Maybe I should print a few copies of this tent and store in the suitcase.

Comment: Or learn to live with one set of sheets for your whole stay. (Unless you have an accident that makes your bed dirty.)